# Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that this serie  diverges?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

From the Taylor expansion of $e^u$ when $u\to 0$,
$$n^{1/n}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln n} = 1+\frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$
so that
$$
1-n^{1/n} = -\frac{\ln n}{n} + o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)
$$
and you can conclude by comparison with the (divergent) series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln n}{n}$.

Comment: **(Not OP)** I think I'm confused. Wouldn't $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \ln (n)=0$ imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n} \ln (n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
 n^{\frac{1}{n}} =1$ meaning that just doing
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-n^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\frac{1}{n}} $$
be sufficient since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ clearly diverges and the other sum is converges? Am I missing something?

Comment: This does not work: both diverge, and you get an indeterminate $\infty-\infty$. $\frac{\ln n}{n}\to 0$ implies $e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}} \to e^0 = 1$ as you wrote, so... $\sum_n e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}  = \infty$, it does not converge at all.

Comment: Oh man I need sleep. I accidentally thought $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\frac{1}{n}$ was converging. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek No worries.